# Sencha Touch JSONPinclude via https doesn't work on some android devices

Tags: android, cordova, sencha-touch, jsonp, script-tag

I have got a scripttag proxy that reads json data from a remote https url. In the emulator, on iPhones and on some android devices it works. But there are some Androids (HTC Desire and a Motrola Milestone I don't know) that doesn't work.

**excerp of Kunde.js**

```
proxy: {
    type: 'scripttag',
    url: API_URL + 'getKundenListe',
    reader: {
        type: 'json',
        root: 'kunden'
    },
    listeners: {
        exception: function(proxy, request, operation) {
            alert('exception during scripttag proxy operation');
        }
    }
},
```

The exception displays all the time on that android devices.

Via debug.phonegap.com I figured out that the remote device added this script tag to the head section:

```
<script src="https://apps.kdo.de/wuakz/json/getKundenListe?_dc=1329298561166&limit=25&callback=stcCallback1001" async="true" type="text/javascript" id="stcScript1001"></script>
```

**On the devices that doesn't work, the script tag is two times in the head section.**

The response of this request looks like this:

```
stcCallback1001({"kunden":[{"kdnr":"0100","bezeichnung":"Stadt Oldenburg","kuerzel":"OL"}],"status":"ok"})
```

I have also added the INTERNET permission to the AndroidManifest.

Any ideas on how to figure out the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To close this out:
It worked when upgrading to Android 2.3.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using phonegap there is no need to use the `scripttag proxy`. You can use the `ajax proxy` and it will work, because it's not running in a browser, so there is no such security constrain.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I would like to use the scripttag proxy to have the same codebase for the webapp. On Android 2.3 everything works fine, therefore I set the minimum Api level to that version.

Comment: Thanks for the info about Android 2.3.